# Inconsistent results using Metal Performance Shaders between MacBook Pro and iMac

Tags: ios, swift, macos, metal, metal-performance-shaders

I'm trying to dip my feet into the waters of GPU programming for the first time. I thought I'd start out with something simple and use pre-made kernels (hence the MPS) and just try issuing the commands to the GPU.

My attempt was to simply sum up all values between 1 and 1000. I put each value in a 1x1 matrix and used the MPS Matrix Sum.

On my MacBook Pro, this works as I expect it to.

On my iMac, it gives [0.0] as the result. I figured this was to do with memory, since I use an iGPU on my MacBook Pro and a dGPU on my iMac, however, as far as I can tell, the storageModeShared shouldn't result in this. I even tried adding .synchronize() to the result matrix before trying to read from it, even though I'm pretty sure it shouldn't be necessary with storageModeShared.

The code isn't elegant cause it's just for quickly understanding the workings of issuing commands with MPS and I've tried fixing issues for a little while without keeping track of structure, but it should still be fairly easy to read; If not let me know and I'll refactor it.

The print statements are just to try and debug, aside from print(output)

I hate to paste so much code, but I'm afraid I can't really isolate my issue more.

```
import Cocoa
import Quartz
import PlaygroundSupport
import MetalPerformanceShaders

let device = MTLCopyAllDevices()[0]
print(MTLCopyAllDevices())


let shaderKernel = MPSMatrixSum.init(device: device, count: 1000, rows: 1, columns: 1, transpose: false)


var matrixList: [MPSMatrix] = []
var GPUStorageBuffers: [MTLBuffer] = []
for i in 1...1000 {
    var a = Float32(i)
    var b: [Float32] = []
    let descriptor = MPSMatrixDescriptor.init(rows: 1, columns: 1, rowBytes: 4, dataType: .float32)
    b.append(a)

    let buffer = device.makeBuffer(bytes: b, length: 4, options: .storageModeShared)

    GPUStorageBuffers.append(buffer!)

    let GPUStoredMatrices = MPSMatrix.init(buffer: buffer!, descriptor: descriptor)

    matrixList.append(GPUStoredMatrices)
}

let matrices: [MPSMatrix] = matrixList

print(matrices.count)
print("\n")

print(matrices[4].debugDescription)
print("\n")
var printer: [Float32] = []
let pointer2 = matrices[4].data.contents()
let typedPointer2 = pointer2.bindMemory(to: Float32.self, capacity: 1)
let buffpoint2 = UnsafeBufferPointer(start: typedPointer2, count: 1)

buffpoint2.map({value in
    printer += [value]
})
print(printer)


let CMDQue = device.makeCommandQueue()

let CMDBuffer = CMDQue!.makeCommandBuffer()

var resultMatrix = MPSMatrix.init(device: device, descriptor: MPSMatrixDescriptor.init(rows: 1, columns: 1, rowBytes: 4, dataType: .float32))

shaderKernel.encode(to: CMDBuffer!, sourceMatrices: matrices, resultMatrix: resultMatrix, scale: nil, offsetVector: nil, biasVector: nil, start: 0)

print(CMDBuffer.debugDescription)
CMDBuffer!.commit()
print(CMDBuffer.debugDescription)
print(CMDQue.debugDescription)
let GPUStartTime = CACurrentMediaTime()
CMDBuffer!.waitUntilCompleted()

var output = [Float32]()
resultMatrix.synchronize(on: CMDBuffer!)

let pointer = resultMatrix.data.contents()
let typedPointer = pointer.bindMemory(to: Float32.self, capacity: 1)
let buffpoint = UnsafeBufferPointer(start: typedPointer, count: 1)

buffpoint.map({value in
    output += [value]
})
print(output)
let finish = GPUStartTime - CACurrentMediaTime()
print("\n")
print(finish)
```

Comment: Could you provide the exact models for those two Macs?

Comment: You're creating a new command buffer for the `synchronize()` call, and you're never committing it nor waiting for it to complete. You should just do that `synchronize()` on the command buffer you're already working with, but before you commit it.

Comment: Hey, guy! Thanks for your replies. I think I've found a solution, though I'm still trying to work out why it worked. The resultMatrix I created was created without an associated buffer; I figured this just meant it'd just not have associated data, but it might've meant the GPU had no way of communicating with the MPSMatrix. - I created a new shared buffer for the result Matrix and it now works. I can even run the summing matrices in shared storageMode and the result in shared and that works. Though private mode gives access error even though the CPU shouldn't touch any but the result Matrix.

Comment: And for Idogy: 
2014 MacBook Pro 15" with 2.2GHz i7 and Intel Iris Pro (I believe that's Iris Pro 5200)
2014 iMac 5K 27" with 4GHz i7-4790K and R9M295X